# Can someone have a villager move to their island if they have a villager in boxes?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

My friend has all of their plots full, and one of their villagers is in boxes right now. They are offering for Tex, who’s on my island, and I have to get him in boxes today since Freya is in my campsite and I really want her to move in.

If I get Tex in boxes, is it possible for my friend to come and adopt Tex if they have full plots, but they have a villager in boxes?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can only invite a villager in boxes from another town if you have an empty plot on your island (meaning the villager already moved out and their house has been replaced by the for-sale plot)